# How to connect to docker container's link alias from host

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I have 3 separate pieces to my dockerized application:

- **`nodeapp`**: A `node:latest` docker container running an expressjs app that returns a JSON object when accessed from `/api`. This server is also CORs enabled according to [this site](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html).
- **`nginxserver`**: A `nginx:latest` static server that simply hosts an `index.html` file that allows the user to click a button which would make the XMLHttpRequest to the node server above.
- My **host** machine

The `node:latest` has its port exposed to the host via `3000:80`.

The `nginx:latest` has its port exposed to the host via `8080:80`.

From **host** I am able to access both **nodeapp** and **nginxserver** *individually*: I can make requests and see the JSON object returned from the node server using `curl` from the command line, and the button (index.html) is visible on the screen when I hit `localhost:8080`.

However, when I try clicking the button the call to `XMLHttpRequest('GET', 'http://nodeapp/api', true)` fails without seemingly hitting the `nodeapp` server (no log is present). I'm assuming this is because **host** does not understand `http://nodeapp/api`.

Is there a way to tell docker that while a container is running to add its container linking alias to my hosts file?

I don't know if my question is the proper solution to my problem. It looks as though I'm getting a CORs error returned but I don't think it is ever hitting my server. Does this have to do with accessing the application from my host machine?

[Here is a link to an example repo](https://github.com/adam-beck/docker-link-cors-problem)

***Edit***: I've noticed that the when using the stack that clicking the button sends **a response from my nginx container**. I'm confused as to why it is routing through that server as the `nodeapp` is in my `hosts` file so it should recognize the correlation there?

Comment: u r correct, your host doesn't understand nodeapp, you can use nginx redirect feature to point to nginx always

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**:

`nodeapp` exists in internal network, which is visible to your `nginxserver` only, you can check this by enter `nginxserver`

```
docker exec -it nginxserver bash 
# cat /etc/hosts
```

Most important, your service setup is not correct, `nginxserver` shall act as reverse proxy in front of `nodeapp`

```
host (client) -> nginxserver -> nodeapp
```

**Dirty Quick Solution**:

If you really really want your client (**host**) to access internal application `nodeapp`, then you simple change below code

```
XMLHttpRequest('GET', 'http://nodeapp/api', true)
```

To

```
XMLHttpRequest('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/api', true)
```

Since in your `docker-compose.yml`, `nodeapp` service port `80` is exposed in home network as `3000`, which can be accessed directly.

**Better solution**

You need redesign your service stack, to make `nginxserver` as frontend node, see one sample http://schempy.com/2015/08/25/docker_nginx_nodejs/